# How to forecast one output with multiple features by LSTM model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, lstm, prediction

I am playing with some stocks `timeseries data` and trying to predict the trend with `multivariate features`. Below is the sample `dataset` I have which including different `technical indicators` including `moving average`, `Parabolic SAR` etc for each stocks. From different online sources, most of them are predicting one stock with `one feature` like "Close" price a time. How can I make use all the stocks' features to predict one output let's say `S&P's close price`. I know it may not help boosting the prediction accuracy but I am not sure what I am training right now and hope having more insight on LSTM model.

[image]

Basically, I put the whole dataset in and do the scaling and training stuffs. How could the prediction being specified on one column?

Code:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaled_feature_data = scaler.fit_transform(feature_data)
X_train, y_train = training_set[:, :-1], training_set[:, -1]
X_test, y_test = testing_set[:, :-1], testing_set[:, -1]
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1]))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
```

Model:

```
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression problem. You are predicting one variable. So last layers may look like

```py
model_lstm.add(Dense(1))
model_lstm.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Also, you probably don't need to return_sequences for each of input tokens. If `return_sequences=true`, then an output will be a matrix (actually (batch_size, num_tokens, num_features)), that cannot be automatically flattened to vector (batch_size, num_features) that is expected to be an input of Dense(1) layer. Just use an output of a last LSTM node. For this, set `return_sequences=false`. Its values depends on previous tokens, so you won't lose much information from them.

The whole model may look like this:

```py
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_lstm.add(Dense(1))
model_lstm.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

If you want more layers it will become:

```py
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[-1])))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))
model_lstm.add(Dense(1))
model_lstm.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain my question clearly. Actually I am wondering how can all features, lets say 10 technical indicator features, can help predict the one price column? Or actually LSTM is doing the prediction column by column, like each technical column is independent with each other?

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I am wondering how can all features, lets say 10 technical indicator features, can help predict the one price column?

Don't know if i understand you correctly.But thats what a ML does, it tries to find corelations between the features and how they can be used to predict something. So maybe, the "DE30" has (or seems to have) a influence on the price and is therfore helpful. Was that your question?

> rom different online sources, most of them are predicting one stock with one feature like "Close" price a time
> I guess that for simplification. Therefore they used only one feature

Let my know if that was what you asked for..